# How to shuffle a list of tuples?

Tags: python

I am trying to shuffle a list of tuples in Python,

```
import random
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
b = random.shuffle(a)
```

but when I run the above, `b` is `None`.

How can I shuffle a list of tuples?

Comment: Shuffle works _in place_ meaning it modifies `a`.

Answer (score 6):

To shuffle a but return the shuffled list and leave `a` intact use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
import random
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
b = random.sample(a, k=len(a))
print(b)
#[(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)]
print(a)
#[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
```

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles a list in place so the return value is `None`.

```
import random
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
#[(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Just an extra comment, if you need the original list just make a copy of it beforehand.

Comment: If you read the docs it says just to use sample.

Comment: right, or use `sample()`

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer was downvoted though. I had intentions on including more detail just needed links and such. Wanted to get the answer for why what was happening down first

Comment: I guess because of the duplicate already having an exhaustive answer, but cannot tell for sure. Perhaps this was discussed on meta?

Comment: Ahh, page didn't update reflecting it was closed for me had to F5

Comment: Upvoted, but I would add, the fact that mutator methods in Python tend to return `None` is merely a *convention*. Other languages or third party APIs may support fluent interfaces, in which case, mutator methods *could* return the object itself